# Use FFMPEG to blend streaming overlay onto second stream

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp, overlays

I'm trying to build a form of monitoring that can be superimposed onto a live stream.

**Monitor Overlay**

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/pool/livestream -filter_complex \
  "nullsrc=1024x576[1:v]; \
  [0:a]showvolume=v=0:o=1:t=0:f=0.1,drawbox=x=ih-40:y=0:w=40:h=ih[volume]; \
  [1:v]drawtext=x=(main_w/2)-(text_w/2):y=text_h:fontsize=30:fontcolor=white:borderw=1:text='Stream Label',scale=-1:-1[label]; \
  [label][volume]overlay=x=main_w-40:y=0[output]" \
  -map "[output]" -f flv rtmp://localhost/pool/livestream_overlay
```

What I would like to accomplish is that this stream be superimposed onto the original stream and pushed to a third RTMP endpoint, like this:

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/pool/livestream -i rtmp://localhost/pool/livestream_overlay \
  -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=shortest=1[output]" \
  -f flv rtmp://localhost/pool/livestream_monitor
```

While the workflow seems to be working, the overlay is not blending (subtracted?) onto the original video:

Actual output

[image: Actual output]

Expected output

[image: Expected output]

Note: codec options have been removed for brevity's sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/pool/livestream -filter_complex \
"[0:a]showvolume=v=0:o=1:t=0:f=0.1,drawbox=x=iw-40:y=0:w=40:h=ih[volume]; \
 [0:v]drawtext=x=(W-tw)/2:y=th:fontsize=30:fontcolor=white:borderw=1:text='Stream Label'[label]; \
 [label][volume]overlay=x=W-40:y=0[output]" \
-map "[output]" -map 0:a -f flv rtmp://localhost/pool/livestream_monitor
```

None of the usual FLV codecs support alpha, so in the 2nd command, you would have to perform chroma keying, which is usually subpar in ffmpeg. So, you can do it in the same command.

Comment: I was using this approach originally, but thought that generating the overlay separately would make it convenient if the channel being monitored had audio only. Having played around with it, I've come to realise that it's a massive waste of processing.

Comment: @Mulvya just to clarify that VP6 codec, in FLV, does support alpha (but its  alpha channel is not supported in FFmpeg). Also instead of chroma-key couldn't a layer blend-mode do the trick? (I suppose it works better with greyscale than Asker's shown green image).

Answer (score 1):

So after playing around all day, I stumbled across the answer purely by accident.

Simply change `nullsrc=1024x576[1:v]` to `pad=1024:576:0:0:black[1:v]`. The black background disappears, and the rest remain.

**Source:** A memory of a documentary long ago about tricks used in broadcasting, talking about how white text on a black background superimposed on film made the black transparent. Hopefully, there's a film buff here that can explain it better

Comment: About _"white text on a black background... made the black transparent"_ This can be achieved by using image as alpha channel (where black areas mean transparent and white means fully visible) usually it's used to mask. Also can try a layer blending mode (like multiply, screen, etc). If this was my task, for static text/overlay, I would just use PNG (that was pre-saved with transparency). Here is an old [**example where text/logo are one PNG image**](https://www.facebook.com/VCone.co.uk/videos/10153750986562341/) overlayed via FFmpeg. (Just an FBook link for now, video has suggestive clothing)